# unable to import evernote.api.client (evernte sdk)

Tags: python, sdk, evernote

i'm trying to get started with evernote SDK , i'm using ubuntu 13.04

i installed the SDK via :

```
pip install evernote
```

but when i want to test it using :

```
python -c 'from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient'
```

i got this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api.client
```

What is the problem ?

EDIT : `pip install evernote` works fine i guess , it gives me this :

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): evernote in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/evernote-1.24.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauth2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from evernote)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2->evernote)
Cleaning up...
```

here is the turorial : http://dev.evernote.com/start/guides/python.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty old already, but I bet more people will hit it, so I'll put the answer here. It seems to be a surprisingly common issue that doesn't have an answer anywhere.

Note how the error complains about api.client but not evernote.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api.client`

Most likely, the problem is that OP has a script in his path called evernote.py, which I guess is a common name people use to name their first evernote script. Rename the script to something less obvious and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like
`pip install evernote` don't do what it is suppose to do:

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release
openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.2
CODENAME = Mantis

pip install evernote
Downloading/unpacking evernote
  Downloading evernote-1.24.0.macosx-10.8-x86_64.tar.gz (326kB): 326kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package evernote
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 16, in 
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-root/evernote/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 16, in 

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-root/evernote/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/evernote
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

You can fix that with:

```
    pip -v install evernote==1.23.2
```

and everything works just fine!

Comment: No i think it works just fine  
<code>pip install evernote</code>
it gives me this : 
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): evernote in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/evernote-1.24.0-py2.7.egg
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauth2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from evernote)
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2->evernote)
    Cleaning up...

Comment: You can try to remove it and use 1.23.2 version

Comment: still the same problem 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api.client

Comment: `import evernote.api` ? :)

Comment: import evernote.api
not working

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the version of Evernote SDK for Python with:

```
pip freeze
```

If `import evernote` works but `from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient` doesn't, you might happen to use 1.23.0 version or older since EvernoteClient class was introduced in 1.23.1.

Also please check your site-packages directory to make sure any older version is not loaded.

Comment: How about this (updated)? It should show which version you are actually using.
`import pkg_resources; package = pkg_resources.require("evernote"); print package;`